# How to transfer data from revolving spreadsheet to a master sheet without loosing previous data?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Using google sheets I am attempting to create a running Master-Sheet that pulls data from an Import-Sheet. The imported data from Import-Sheet adds the data to the first blank row in the Master-Sheet without deleting previously imported data. Also, if possible, the imported data would removes/replace any duplicates found on the Master-Sheet. Upon completion of the Import-Sheet data into the Master-Sheet, the Import-Sheet is cleared with all data remaining in the Master-Sheet.

Comment: Do you have any examples of code you've written and/or tried already?

Comment: No unfortunately I do not. I typically work within Excel but this needs to be on Google Sheets. In the past I have only used queries to pull data within google sheets. I am a novice when it comes to Google scripts.